# Azure b2c mfa with SMS only when signup not sign in

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have set up with the default signin and signup flow. I have also enabled mfa.

This works fine. Is it possible to configure the mfa only for signup and not for sign in?

The mfa is only needed for password change or to access certain pages in the app.

regards
Stefan

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the build-in user flow: `Sign up and sign in`, the MFA is for both signup and sign in at the same time.

A workaround is to use the two user flows `Sign up v2` and `Sign in v2` separately.

You just need to enable MFA only for `Sign up v2` user flow.

Comment: Great Work!! Thanks for the example